# pyspark recursive imports from py-files zip

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark job that has quite a few dependencies. So I did a `pip install -t reqs -r requirements.txt` and then zipped up the `reqs` directory. I then passed that to `--py-files` so it would be available on all nodes.

I have a file that imports pandas which is successfully found in the zip file. However, pandas imports numpy which isn't found even though it is also in that zip file:

```
File "./spark-job.zip/model/transforms/parser.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
File "./reqs.zip/pandas/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Note that `pandas` is found in `reqs.zip` but numpy is not. And note that numpy is in the zip file. I'm quite sure it's there:

```
$ unzip -l reqs.zip | grep pandas | head -10
        0  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas-0.20.2.dist-info/
    97277  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas-0.20.2.dist-info/RECORD
      109  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas-0.20.2.dist-info/WHEEL
        7  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas-0.20.2.dist-info/top_level.txt
     1102  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas-0.20.2.dist-info/metadata.json
        4  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas-0.20.2.dist-info/INSTALLER
     3471  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas-0.20.2.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
     4452  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas-0.20.2.dist-info/METADATA
        0  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas/
        0  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas/formats/

$ unzip -l reqs.zip | grep numpy | head -40
        0  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy-1.13.0.dist-info/
    52437  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy-1.13.0.dist-info/RECORD
      109  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy-1.13.0.dist-info/WHEEL
        6  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy-1.13.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
     1330  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy-1.13.0.dist-info/metadata.json
        4  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy-1.13.0.dist-info/INSTALLER
      884  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy-1.13.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
     2217  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy-1.13.0.dist-info/METADATA
    22668  2017-06-28 20:58   sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle_utils.py
     8440  2017-06-28 20:58   sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle_compat.py
    23222  2017-06-28 20:58   sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py
     7468  2017-06-28 20:58   sklearn/externals/joblib/__pycache__/numpy_pickle_compat.cpython-34.pyc
    16545  2017-06-28 20:58   sklearn/externals/joblib/__pycache__/numpy_pickle_utils.cpython-34.pyc
    15643  2017-06-28 20:58   sklearn/externals/joblib/__pycache__/numpy_pickle.cpython-34.pyc
    10508  2017-06-28 20:58   scipy/_lib/__pycache__/_numpy_compat.cpython-34.pyc
    11513  2017-06-28 20:58   scipy/_lib/_numpy_compat.py
        0  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas/compat/numpy/
    12344  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas/compat/numpy/function.py
        0  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas/compat/numpy/__pycache__/
     2399  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas/compat/numpy/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc
    10150  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas/compat/numpy/__pycache__/function.cpython-34.pyc
     2213  2017-06-28 20:58   pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py
        0  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/
        0  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/.libs/
 38513408  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/.libs/libopenblasp-r0-39a31c03.2.18.so
  1023960  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/.libs/libgfortran-ed201abd.so.3.0.0
        0  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/testing/
     2705  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/testing/print_coercion_tables.py
     8036  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/testing/decorators.py
    75541  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/testing/utils.py
    19120  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/testing/nosetester.py
    13834  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/testing/noseclasses.py
        0  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/testing/__pycache__/
      713  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/testing/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc
     9827  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/testing/__pycache__/noseclasses.cpython-34.pyc
     8572  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/testing/__pycache__/decorators.cpython-34.pyc
    67010  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/testing/__pycache__/utils.cpython-34.pyc
     2712  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/testing/__pycache__/print_coercion_tables.cpython-34.pyc
    15253  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/testing/__pycache__/nosetester.cpython-34.pyc
      805  2017-06-28 20:58   numpy/testing/__pycache__/setup.cpython-34.pyc
```

Any ideas why this isn't working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I may have answered my own question. As described in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6764 pyspark used `zipimport` to import things from `--py-files` and `zipimport` only supports .py, .pyc and .pyo files. Notably it does not support modules, like numpy, that require native code.